# How to optimize MongoDB find query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-optimization, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongo read query which looks like following.

```
data class Resource( val assignmentId: String, val referrerId: String, val studentIds: Set<String>)

fun findSubmissions(resources: List<Resource>): Flux<Submission> {
        val criteria = resources.map { (assignmentId, referrerId, students) ->
            Criteria.where("assignmentId").`is`(assignmentId).and("referrerId").`is`(referrerId).and("studentId").`in`(students)
        }.toTypedArray()

        val query = Query().addCriteria(Criteria().orOperator(*criteria))
        return template.find(query, Submission::class.java)
    }
}
```

Document schema of Submission looks like this

```
{
  assignmentId: "",
  referrerId: "",
  studentId: "",
  status: ""
}
```

Looks like this query is affecting the performance and hogging the CPU, which could be because of the way `OR` clause has been written.
Any ideas how this query can be rewritten in a better way?

Comment: Can you tell what is the query condition is in this statement: `val query = Query().addCriteria(Criteria().orOperator(*criteria))`

Comment: So the current query is basically doing this:

```where (assignmentId == "aid1" and referrerId = "rid1" and studentId in ["sid1", "sid2"]) OR
where (assignmentId == "aid2" and referrerId = "rid2" and studentId in ["sid11", "sid22"]) OR
....```

Comment: So in this each row in the collection will have to be checked for all the OR clauses(considering worst case where it matches the last clause) - and that could be the reason of it affecting performace

Comment: For performance improvement you can use indexes on the fields used in the query - useful if the number of documents in the collection is large (e.g., 500,000 or greater). See the topics of [compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) and [OR Clauses and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#-or-clauses-and-indexes).